# error installing oracle 11g on Ubuntu 17.04 Mate

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, proxy, oracle-database

I am trying to install Oracle 11g on my Ubuntu Mate 17.04 machine. In one of the installation steps, I am required to key in the proxy details/credentials.

In our college, there is a wifi as well as a LAN connection. The same proxy settings are used to access Internet for wifi as well as LAN.

However, when I enter the proxy details, it says that the values entered are incorrect and asks me to reenter the credentials. I cross-checked it the /etc/apt/apt.conf file, the browser's settings as well as Network proxy settings present in the control center. Everywhere the same proxy settings are same. Then why am I getting such a message.

See the images for screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Descriptions are as follows

(a) Details entered during the installation
(b) error given by installer
(c) content of apt.conf file
(d) browser's proxy settings (Mozilla Firefox)
(e) proxy setting in the control center